# How to select an element from a ComboBox menu using Vaadin Testbench?

Tags: combobox, vaadin, test-bench

I am doing some integration tests with vaadin version 7.6.4 and Testbench (4.0.3).

I have a view with several comboboxes. One of them has this property `comboBox.setTextInputAllowed(false);` For testing purposes, I want to change the default value on the combobox and I need to select a different element then the default one.

To select an element I have tried the following code:

```
 $(ComboBoxElement.class).selectByText("ElementName");
```

But this only works when `comboBox.setTextInputAllowed(true);`

I also have tried to use `sendkeys()` to change the selected value:

```
$(ComboBoxElement.class).openPopup();
$(ComboBoxElement.class).sendKeys(keys.ARROW_DOWN);
$(ComboBoxElement.class).endKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

This code opens the comboBox popup correctly but doesn't select any item.  Neither if I set the focus with `setFocus()`;

Could anybody please tell me how can I change the value of a combobox with property `setTextInputAllowed(false)`?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, your scenario does not seem to work as expected, at least with Vaadin 7.7.3 & TB 4.1.0.alpha1 I had.
Looking at the [sources](https://github.com/vaadin/testbench/blob/master/vaadin-testbench-api/src/main/java/com/vaadin/testbench/elements/ComboBoxElement.java#L43) (line 43 atm), in the particular case when a combo is read-only, TestBench will make it *writeable*, send the specified text, and pick the corresponding item from the popup suggestion list. Nonetheless, during a small debug session, you can easily see that `text.equals(popupSuggestions.get(0)` is not equal to `Region - 5` as they were hoping.

[image: debug]

In conclusion, there's a chance that this is a bug in TB itself. I have a few suppositions but I did not have the time to investigate thoroughly atm how and why.

As a workaround, you can open the popup, use an XPath expression to find the correct item and click it. I have a demo app with a combo containing items named `Region - 1` to `Region - 10`.

[image: combo content]

To select `Region - 5` I did:

```
@Test
public void shouldOpenGridColumnVisibilityPopupAndSelectItems() {
    getDriver().get("http://localhost:8080/");
    ComboBoxElement combo = $(ComboBoxElement.class).first();
    combo.openPopup();
    findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='VAADIN_COMBOBOX_OPTIONLIST']//span[text()='Region - 5']")).click();
}
```

Result:

[image: workaround result]